# Automatically insert the input form by selectpicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make auto input by **selectpicker** then calculate that form, but my code below is not auto input except I click first the input form, the calculate **javascript** is working but I want to make the Input Price automatically has value when i select the package & trip without click the input form first.

sorry for my bad english grammar and i just started learning programming. thank you, this my code below :

**HTML**

```
<label>Package</label>
<select  onblur="findTotal()" class="selectpicker" id="package">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select package...</option>
  <option value="Engagement">Engagement</option>
  <option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<br/>

<label>Trip</label>
<select  onblur="findTotal()" class="selectpicker" id="trip">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select trip...</option>
  <option value="shorttrip">Short Trip</option>
  <option value="longttrip">Long Trip</option>
</select>

<br/><br/>

<label>Package Price</label>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="packageprice" placeholder="autoinput by selectpicker" />
<br/>
<label>Trip Price</label>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="tripprice" placeholder="autoinput by selectpicker" />
<br/>
<label>Tip</label>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" placeholder="manual input"  />


<br/><br/>
<label>Total Price</label>
<input type="text" name="result" id="total" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    var paket = document.getElementById('package').value;
    var trp = document.getElementById('trip').value;
    
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    
    if (paket == "Engagement") {
        document.getElementById('packageprice').value = "1000";
    } else if (paket == "Wedding") {
      document.getElementById('packageprice').value = "2000";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('packageprice').value = "0";
    }
    
    if (trp == "shorttrip") {
        document.getElementById('tripprice').value = "3000";
    } else if (trp == "longttrip") {
      document.getElementById('tripprice').value = "4000";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('tripprice').value = "0";
    }
    
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

or you can view the code on JS Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ryh7vpwa/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **oninput** instead of **onblur** on the elements implementing findTotal function

```
<select  oninput="findTotal()" class="selectpicker" id="package">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select package...</option>
  <option value="Engagement">Engagement</option>
  <option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<br/>

<label>Trip</label>
<select  oninput="findTotal()" class="selectpicker" id="trip">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select trip...</option>
  <option value="shorttrip">Short Trip</option>
  <option value="longttrip">Long Trip</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, i just use onblur from other reference and i dont know what is that for, now i know, thank you.